# how to detect and extract multiple occurrences of a group in a regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract specific groups from a given string using regular expressions in Java. The pattern includes an option to capture an unknown number of `<np>` elements after the "such as" phrase, and I want to be able to save all of them. However, in my current implementation, I seem to be overwriting some of the groups and missing others.

Here's the code I have so far:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Detector {
    private final String input;
    private final String pattern;
    private final String lemma;
    private final Map<Integer, String> groups;

    public Detector(String input, String pattern, String lemma) {
        this.input = input;
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.lemma = lemma;
        this.groups = new HashMap<>();
        processInput();
    }

    public void processInput() {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);

        int groupIndex = 1;

        if (matcher.find()) {
            groups.put(groupIndex, matcher.group(1));
            groupIndex++;

            for (int i = 2; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                String group = matcher.group(i);
                if (group != null ) {
                    groups.put(groupIndex, group);
                    groupIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(groups);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "<np>semitic languages such as <np>Hebrew ,<np>mip ,<np>bip ,<np>bop or <np>Arabic";
        String pattern = "<np>,?([\\w\\s]+)\\s+such as\\s+<np>([\\w]+)\\s(?:,<np>([\\w]+)\\s)*(?:(?:and|or)\\s<np>([\\w]+))?";
        Detector suchAs = new Detector(input, pattern, "mip");
    }
}
```

The current output I'm getting is `{1=semitic languages, 2=Hebrew, 3=bop, 4=Arabic}`, but it seems that I'm missing the groups mip and bip. I suspect that I'm overwriting them, but I'm not sure how to save them before they get overwritten.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
edit: i was given an easier task each np will be marked at its beggining and end as follows  semitic languages such as Hebrew,bip bop or Arabic are composed of consonants and voyels i still cant get it to work but it should make things easier

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following pattern, although, there will be additional text within the captures.

```
(?:<np>(.+?)(?=<np>|$))+?
```

And, you can populate the *groups* map as follows.

```java
public void processInput() {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);

    int groupIndex = 1;

    while (matcher.find())
        groups.put(groupIndex++, matcher.group(1));

    System.out.println(groups);
}
```

Output

```
{1=semitic languages such as , 2=Hebrew ,, 3=mip ,, 4=bip ,, 5=bop or , 6=Arabic}
```

You could then, remove the additional text from within the program, or add a set of values within the pattern.

```
(?:<np>(.+?)(?=(?: languages such as | ,| or )<np>|$))+?
```

Output

```
{1=semitic, 2=Hebrew, 3=mip, 4=bip, 5=bop, 6=Arabic}
```

Comment: this wont work because  the languages is just an example for the following Hearst pattern NP {,} such as NP {, NP, ..., {and|or} NP}.

Comment: @yuvalcohen, interesting.  Can you adapt the pattern?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @yuvalcohen, the regex pattern.

Comment: i can write whatever regex pattern i want as long as it works

Comment: @yuvalcohen, ok, so, can you provide more examples?  I'm not sure of your inquiry, here.